# How to get all DEXs addresses?

Tags: decentralized-exchange

I'm searching everywhere and can't find a way to get a list of all DEXs addresses.

Found 0x.org but it just displays a few of them. On coinMarketCap it shows all the exchanges not only the DEXs. Same with coingecko.

Does anyone know where can I find this data?

Appreciate

Comment: What do you mean under the "DEXs addresses". Do you need the list of all PAIRs for each DEX (Uniswap, etc)?

Comment: Thanks for commenting. Yes, my plan is to find all the DEXs, at least all the clones of Uniswap on the Ethereum network. And get from each one their Factory contract. With this I can call from the contract allPairs(), etc,.. Any suggestion where to find this info? Appreciate

Answer (score 0):

The website contains a list of DEX exchanges from Ethereum, BSC, Polygon...etc. You can take a look:

https://defiprime.com/exchanges

Comment: Appreciate your answer, but on the link it just shows a few of them... I would like to find all them.

Comment: How do you know you have found all of them?

Comment: @Zaesar What is a DEX? You won't be able to find all DEXes unless you can say what a DEX is

Comment: a DEX is a Decentralized Exchange

Comment: @YongjianP. well I was hoppening to find a list where there are all listed. Listed on all the different chains.